# WiX - protect the registry value when upgrade an application

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a wix based setup (MSI) and want to protect user settings, which are stored in the registry under HKCU, when updating my application.

For now, when I upgrade my application every registry value will be overwritten, so that the user has to set his settings again.

I also want to remove all settings, when uninstall the whole application.

Can anybody help?

My code looks like this:

```
 <Component Id="REGISTRY_ReConnect" Guid="$(var.GUID_REGISTRY_ReConnect)">
    <RegistryValue Id="_REGISTRY_ReConnect" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\exampleX\MBCA" Name="ReConnect" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
 </Component>
```

Answer (score 2):

For each of the settings in registry do the following:

Define a Property containing the default value of the setting.

Define a RegistrySearch which will extract a value of the setting from registry and put it into another Property.

Use SetProperty to (conditionally) upgrade the value of first property with the value extracted from the registry.

In your Component/RegistryValue/@Value use the value of the first property instead of explicit value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="MyProduct" Language="1033" Version="1.1.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="81a34cee-f0da-4135-9f37-53e02e4b450a">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perUser" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Media Id="1" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyProduct1" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolde">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyProduct" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <Property Id="ReConnect" Value="1" />
    <Property Id="OLDRECONNECT">
        <RegistrySearch Id="ReConnectSearch" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\exampleX\MBCA" Name="ReConnect" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
    <SetProperty Id="ReConnect" Value="[OLDRECONNECT]" After="AppSearch">OLDRECONNECT</SetProperty>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="REGISTRY_ReConnect">
            <RegistryValue Id="_REGISTRY_ReConnect" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\exampleX\MBCA" Name="ReConnect" Value="[ReConnect]" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: This works also, when the installer has to write to HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Comment: @creg Yes, why not?  See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern/ for reference

Comment: @creg It will only work for HKCU if the same user that did the first install, also does the upgrade install. That's why it's generally not a good idea to let the installer read or write HKCU.

Comment: @zett42 Maybe you're right but when you give someone a tool to write under HKCU you can assume, he will use it. The Visual Studio Installer seems also to handle the problem properly.

Comment: @creg I assume that the application is also installed for the current user.  Then each user has its own install/upgrade/uninstall sequence.  If the application is installed for all users, you cannot add/remove settings for all users into their profiles.

Comment: @dvorn Thank you, I've tried it and it works but only when you use per user installation (thanks also to @zett42). Unfortunately I need a per machine (for all users) installation. But what I am not understanding is, that a Visual Studio Setup Project can manage my concern: that is an installation that doesn't touch the registry settings of my users (with or without any registry values set by the installer).

Comment: When an application is installed for all users, installer cannot install user settings.  Note that a user may be added after the application installation.  In this case, it is the application itself who creates settings. They will survive the application upgrade but they won't be deleted automatically on application uninstall.  But you can handle that using the ActiveSetup technology.